# Configuring swapfile error

Tags: linux, oracle, unix, oracle-11g

I installed oracle linux 6 on my desktop but I forgot to configure the swapfile, I want to install oracle 11gr2 on it and it requires 2gig or ram, if I type the following commands on the terminal I get these

```
[root@localhost ~]# grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1789764 kB
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@localhost ~]# grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo
SwapTotal:             0 kB
[root@localhost ~]# df -k /tmp
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4            100704696   5106508  90482644   6% /
[root@localhost ~]# df -k 
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4            100704696   5106508  90482644   6% /
tmpfs                   894880       100    894780   1% /dev/shm
[root@localhost ~]#
```

How do I set the swap file to the required ram for oracle installation which requires 2gig 
any ideas on how I can go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type the following commands on the terminal

```
swapoff -a
cd /
dd if=/dev/zero of=swapfile bs=2048 count=1048576 //this is 512x2048= 1048576 blocks
mkswapfile -v1 /swapfile
vi /etc/rc.local
```

then click insert and type

```
swapon /swapfile
```

escape and press shift then wq

```
reboot
```

check

```
grep SwapToatal /proc/meminfo
```

Answer (score 2):

The following examples shows how to create a 100-MB swap file called /files/swapfile.

```
# mkdir /files
# mkfile 100m /files/swapfile
# swap -a /files/swapfile
# vi /etc/vfstab
(An entry is added for the swap file):
/files/swapfile   -      -       swap     -     no     -
# swap -l
swapfile             dev  swaplo blocks   free
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s1   136,1      16 1638608 1600528
/files/swapfile        -       16 204784  204784
```